# How to upgrade a multi_index table in a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, eosio.cdt

I have initially the following multi_index table:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] plastict
{
    uint64_t id;
    uint64_t type;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
};
typedef eosio::multi_index<"items"_n, item> items;
items items_table;
```

I have deployed initial smart contract and now am I trying to add a new field to the the table `items`. According to the info, I have found in a couple of EOS issues, I have added the new field at the end of the table struct:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] plastict
{
    uint64_t id;
    uint64_t type;
    uint64_t state;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
};
typedef eosio::multi_index<"items"_n, item> items;
items items_table;
```

Unfortunately, after I have re-compiled and re-deployed the smart contract, when I try to read the table content, I get the following:

```
Error: {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":3015013,"name":"unpack_exception","what":"Unpack data exception","details":[{"message":"Stream unexpectedly ended; unable to unpack field 'state' of struct 'item'","file":"abi_serializer.cpp","line_number":307,"method":"_binary_to_variant"}]}}
```

> I don't need backward compatibility, thats why I am not wrapping the new field within **binary_extension** type, but I want to keep all the data already inserted and keep it accessible.

Appreciate any ideas and remarks ?

Comment: Do you care about the previous data in the table or do you just want to have the table accept the new struct and be done with it?

Comment: Yes, I need the already inserted data in the table and keep it accessible.

Comment: Ok submitted an answer that addresses both situations. Also made an example to go along with the answer https://github.com/netuoso/eos-migrate-demo. Hope it helps; this is a common question.

Answer (score 3):

#### If you don't care about the data from `old_table`:

- Erase all records from `old_table`
- Deploy NEWCONTRACT with modified `old_table`

---

#### If you want to persist the data from `old_table`:

- Define the new and old structs/tables in NEW_CONTRACT1
- Write a function that will move data from `old_table` to `new_table`; adding new column
- Deploy NEW_CONTRACT2 version that has `old_table` modified the way you want
- Reverse the data migration function to move data from `new_table` back to old_table

Now your user will be able to query `old_table` the way they did before and the contract will not throw an exception. You simply cannot modify a table that has any existing data inside of it.

*I have an example contract for this process you can view at: https://github.com/netuoso/eos-migrate-demo*

*Note: If you have a table with many records, it is possible the transaction time limit will be reached. In that situation, you could modify the migrate function to only move a limited number of records each time you call it.*

Comment: quite complicated but true

Comment: Both suggestions are not the solutions I am trying to find. I need to keep the same contract and the data already written in the contract tables, so I was wondering is there a working solution where I can upgrade the already existing table and redeploy the entire smart contract again and continue working with the new version of the contract/table - without breaking the table and table keys.

Comment: I gave you possible solutions and explained to you clearly that no, it is literally impossible to change the structure of a table with existing data. I've explained how you can preserve your data in the table within the means of EOSIO.